# Как ответить на пост запрос пост ответом в golang?

Tags: json, golang, http

Имеется код на golang, http сервер который принимает на вход post json запрос, парсит его, и выполняет определенный код с данными из запроса, вопрос как ответить на этот запрос так же json оветом, после обработки входящего запроса ?

```
type test_struct2 struct {
    Te string //телеграм
    Na string //имя устройства
    Mi string //минуты
    Se string //секунды

}

func ParseGhPost2(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)

    var rtrt test_struct2
    err := decoder.Decode(&rtrt)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

//здесь обработка данных из запроса,
//далее хотелось бы ответить на входящий запрос json, ответом json 

}

func main() {

    var log = log.New()

    go http.HandleFunc("/", ParseGhPost2)
    go http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:10443", nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кидать панику внутри хэндлера - это плохо. ваше приложение завершится.

```
func JSONError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, bcode string, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(struct{
        Code    string
        Message string
    }{
        Code:    bcode,
        Message: err.Error(),
    })
}

func ParseGhPost2(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)

    var rtrt test_struct2

    err := decoder.Decode(&rtrt)
    if err != nil {
        JSONError(rw, fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal test_struct2: %w", err), "custom_code", http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)

        return // завершаем выполнение
    }
    

    response := struct {
        Answer string
    }{
        "response answer",
    }

    err = json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(&response)
    if err != nil {
        // тут уже вам решать, что сделать надо  
        JSONError(rw, fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal response: %w", err), "custom_code2", http.StatusInternalServerError)

        return
    }

    // запишем новый статус в ответ. 
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    
    // а если дошли сюда - это значит, что все хорошо. завершаем
}
```